# Google chrome not opening in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, google-chrome, gpu

Whenever I try to open google chrome, by `google-chrome` in the terminal it show the following error.

```
ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

It has been a while since this happened, I am new to Ubuntu, could anyone please help me understand this.

I already had installed google chrome before, and was working with it for more than a month right now. after this problem occurred I reinstalled chrome using the following commands.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.de
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This successfully installed chrome, the problem was still persisting

Comment: How strange. I'm using Chrome right now. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1339786/edit) to clearly explain how you installed Chrome.

Comment: Having this exact same issue as of about an hour ago after the update and a restart of chrome. Disabling GPU not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this first in case it's a locked profile problem:

```
rm -f ~/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock
```

If this does not work, you can run this in the terminal and you should get it working :

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Though let me tell you that this will reset all your bookmarks, history. This is kinda like reinstalling chrome. If you had backedup your history into your email id then you can back it up easily after doing this command.

Comment: Thank you very much, even thought it wiped everthing it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. But remember to turn on the sync this time as it's useful for such scenarios. Had you turned on your sync to an email id, you would have been able to back up all your history and bookmarks from it automatically.

Comment: It was synced, my net was slow so it took a while to load the back up, anyway thanks :D